# Transient Copy Constructor weirdness

Tags: c++, stl

I've got this here class defined in a header file:

```
class E_IndexList {
public:
    E_UIntegerList* l;
    inline void *data() { // retrieve packed data: stride depends on type (range)
        return l->data();
    }
    inline void insert(unsigned value) {
        if (value > maxval[l->range]) {
            promote();
            insert(value);
        } else {
            l->push_back(value);
        }
    }
    inline size_t size() {
        return l->size();
    }
    inline unsigned long get(int index) {
        return l->get(index);
    }
    void promote() {
        if (l->range == E_UIntegerList::e_byte) {
            E_UShortList *new_short_list = new E_UShortList(*((E_UByteList*)l));
            delete l;
            l = new_short_list;
        } else if (l->range == E_UIntegerList::e_short) {
            E_UIntList *new_int_list = new E_UIntList(*((E_UShortList*)l));
            delete l;
            l = new_int_list;
        } else ASSERT(false);
    }
    // start off with bytes by default
    E_IndexList() {
        l = new E_UByteList;
    }
    E_IndexList(E_UIntegerList::int_bits range) {
        switch(range) {
        case E_UIntegerList::e_byte:
            l = new E_UByteList;
            break;
        case E_UIntegerList::e_short:
            l = new E_UShortList;
            break;
        case E_UIntegerList::e_int:
            l = new E_UIntList;
            break;
        default:
            ASSERT(false);
            break;
        }
    }
    E_IndexList(const E_IndexList& cpy) { // copy ctor
        switch(cpy.l->range) {
        case E_UIntegerList::e_byte:
            l = new E_UByteList(((E_UByteList*)cpy.l)->list);
            break;
        case E_UIntegerList::e_short:
            l = new E_UShortList(((E_UShortList*)cpy.l)->list);
            break;
        case E_UIntegerList::e_int:
            l = new E_UIntList(((E_UShortList*)cpy.l)->list);
            break;
        default:
            ASSERT(false);
            break;
        }
    }
    ~E_IndexList() {
        delete l;
    }
};
```

Here are some more classes it makes use of:

```
static const unsigned long maxval[] = {0xff,0xffff,0xffffffff};
class E_UIntegerList {
public:
    enum int_bits {e_byte = 0, e_short = 1, e_int = 2};
    virtual ~E_UIntegerList() {}
    int_bits range;
    virtual void push_back(int i) = 0;
    virtual void *data() = 0;
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
    virtual unsigned long get(int index) = 0;
};
struct E_UByteList:public E_UIntegerList {
    std::vector<unsigned char> list;
    E_UByteList() {
        range = e_byte;
    }
    E_UByteList(const std::vector<unsigned char>& copy) {
        list = copy;
    }
    inline void push_back(int i) {
        list.push_back(i);
    }
    inline void *data() { return list.data(); }
    inline size_t size() { return list.size(); }
    inline unsigned long get(int index) { return list[index]; }
};
struct E_UShortList:public E_UIntegerList {
    std::vector<unsigned short> list;
    E_UShortList() {
        range = e_short;
    }
    E_UShortList(const std::vector<unsigned short>& copy) {
        list = copy;
    }
    E_UShortList(const E_UByteList& promotee) {
        range = e_short;
        list.assign(promotee.list.begin(),promotee.list.end()); // assignment should be compatible
    }
    inline void push_back(int i) {
        list.push_back(i);
    }
    inline void *data() { return list.data(); }
    inline size_t size() { return list.size(); }
    inline unsigned long get(int index) { return list[index]; }
};
struct E_UIntList:public E_UIntegerList {
    std::vector<unsigned int> list;
    E_UIntList() {
        range = e_int;
    }
    E_UIntList(const std::vector<unsigned int>& copy) {
        list = copy;
    }
    E_UIntList(const E_UShortList& promotee) {
        range = e_int;
        list.assign(promotee.list.begin(),promotee.list.end());
    }
    inline void push_back(int i) {
        list.push_back(i);
    }
    inline void *data() { return list.data(); }
    inline size_t size() { return list.size(); }
    inline unsigned long get(int index) { return list[index]; }
};
```

Now the way that I use this class is I have a `std::vector<E_IndexList>` that I use as a container of index lists.

The strange behavior is that when I run the program sometimes it has no problems and sometimes it asserts false.

So this is a big red flag for me because something super fishy is going on. I will very likely end up abandoning the entire `E_IndexList` until I start working on game netcode which is a long ways off. But, I'd like to know what's going on here.

Every ctor I have sets the range to a valid value out of the enum in `E_UIntegerList`, so how could that assertion ever get tripped? And I can't begin to come up with an explanation of why the behavior is inconsistent. The test that calls this code is not multi-threaded.

Comment: Which one of the asserts is triggering? (I'm betting on the one in `promote`, just because.)

Comment: ¤ Some constructors don't set the `range` member. E.g. `E_UShortList(const std::vector<unsigned short>& copy)` doesn't. Anyway this is an extreme case of **premature optimization**, so it does not really matter if there are other bugs: just scrap this code. Use a `std::vector<int>`. For example. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define an assignment operator. See [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Answer (score 3):

Your `E_UByteList` from-vector constructor does not set the `range` value.

The entire design is a bit shoddy; you should learn how to use constructor initializer lists, and I would probably endow the base class with a protected constructor that sets the `range` value and which can be invoked from within the derived constructors' initializers.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructors such as this one:

```
E_UByteList(const std::vector<unsigned char>& copy) {
    list = copy;
}
```

do not initialise `range` from the parent `E_UIntegerList` class.